# Why soft body collisions acting strange?

Tags: physics, soft-body

Hello potential informants!

We're setting up a soft-body simulation that involves solid mesh objects (i.e. has internal nodes and edges). We just want to stick with the spring-mass system, and not convolute the physics with the shape-matching technique (i.e. "Soft Body Goal"). We're aiming for physically realistic, and want to use this for a psycho-physical experiment.

In the attached code, I set up a scene that has a soft-body slab supported on either end by passive supports. A cube is initiated directly over the slab. When I make the cube a rigid body, instead of a soft body, it passes right through the slab. When I make it a soft-body, the collisions are strange and non-physical. I've played with all the parameters I can think of, and still haven't been able to achieve a realistic simulation.

Is what I'm trying to do possible in Blender? Am I going about it the wrong way? I get all kinds of strange interactions as a result of the meshes I've created. E.g., if you let a rigid cube drop straight through the slab, when it hits the ground it jumps strangely, as if being acted on at a distance. If you keep the cube as a soft-body, it sticks to the slab, and then they both start floating upward together.

Thanks in advance to all you gurus out there.

Code: http://www.pasteall.org/53426/python

Comment: Try changing the cube's physics settings to Collision, instead of Soft Body or Rigid Body.